# Openshift not forwarding packets to pod

Tags: openshift, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I'm trying to setup a pod which receives packets for port 1234 coming from external hosts. I confirmed via tcpdump that the packets are indeed arriving at the openshift cluster. Now, I have pod AAAA running already which supposed to get the packets for port 1234 (routed or forwarded from the openshift master). We already have assigned an IP for the pod so the docs below has been followed thoroughly to setup the externalIP, ports, etc. I suspect the issue is with the master-config but I cant paste them here.

My question is what are the configs necessary to be put in place in the master-config in order to route port 1234 packets to pod AAAA.

Tried already below Openshift docs:

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_guide/tcp_ingress_external_ports.html
- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/getting_traffic_into_cluster.html#using-ingress-IP-self-service

Answer (score 1):

First of all - You are only referring to a POD. I would recommend to deploy your app as a `Deployment` rather. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359053/kubernetes-pods-vs-deployments-in-google-cloud) and [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

Additionally, in order to expose `Deployments` to the outside world in Kubernetes you have to establish a `Service`. It can expose your app in a few different ways. Please read through [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address-service/) for the details.

If you using any standard app you can usually find an example deployment/service by googling the name of the app and 'kubernetes'.

Comment: OpenShift had its own concept of deployments based around ``DeploymentConfig`` resource. The ``Deployment`` in Kubernetes is actually derived from what OpenShift did before Kubernetes did. In OpenShift, the normal way you deploy an application would also automatically create a ``Service`` object. So be careful of suggesting looking at raw Kubernetes way of doing things, it isn't likely they are doing things in a way that raw Kubernetes methods will always apply.

Comment: Up to this time, Im still checking this issue. I just want to provide more details via this comment. So in tcpdump, i confirmed that in Openshift master, we have the UDP packets arriving at port 1234 for example. Its just that Im not sure how to make the master forward this packet to port 1234 on an Openshift pod. Is this really a missing config on node, master or both(?).

Answer (score 0):

In your master config (etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml), just add

servicesNodePortRange: "1234-1234"

```
kubernetesMasterConfig:
  apiServerArguments:
  controllerArguments:
  masterCount: 1
  masterIP: x.x.x.x
  podEvictionTimeout:
  proxyClientInfo:
    certFile: master.proxy-client.crt
    keyFile: master.proxy-client.key
  schedulerArguments:
  schedulerConfigFile: /etc/origin/master/scheduler.json
  servicesNodePortRange: "1234-1234"
  servicesSubnet: 172.30.0.0/16
  staticNodeNames: []
```

After that, restart atomic-openshift-master service.

Then, create a second service for your deployment with a load balancer type. Assuming your deployment config name is "myapp", create new file similar below,

--- "new-svc.yml" ----

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: myapp
    template: myapp-template
  name: myapp-ext
spec:
  ports:
  - name: myapp
    nodePort: 1234
    port: 1234
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1234
  selector:
    name: myapp
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```

After that, create a new service

```
#oc create -f new-svc.yml
```

Finally, expose the new service "myapp-ext" by adding route (1234 <-- 1234).